# How to get a list of files of the current directory sorted by modification date in a bash script?

Tags: arrays, bash, list, shell, sorting

I would like to get a list (or array) of all files in my current directory which is sorted by modification date. In the terminal, something like `ls -lt` works, but that should not be used in a bash script (http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29)...

I tried to use the `-nt` opterator (https://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2017/11/18/nt-file-test-operator-in-bash/) but I am hoping that there is a more simple and elegant solution to this.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

**In bash with GNU extensions:**

Creating an array

```
mapfile -d '' a < <(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -z -k1,1g | cut -z -d ' ' -f2)
```

or looping over the files:

```
while read -r -d '' _ file; do
   echo "${file}"
done < <(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@ %p\0" | sort -z -k1,1g)
```

Here we build up a list of files with the NULL-character as the delimiter. The field itself consists of the modification date in the epoch followed by a space and the file name. We use `sort` to sort that list by modification date. The output of this is passed to a while loop that `reads` the fields per zero-terminated record. The first field is the modification date which we read in `_` and the remainder is passed to `file`.

**In ZSH:**

If you want to use another shell like zsh, you can just do something like:

```
a=( *(Om) )
```

or

```
for file in *(Om); do echo "${file}"; done
```

here `Om` is a glob-modifier that tells ZSH to sort the output by modification date.

Comment: `-typef` maybe should be `-type f -printf`